# rate limiting and access filter for web application

Tags: web-application, http, access-control, ddos

I had a requirement of rate limiting and dynamically access controlling access to web application dynamically

- I want to be able to rate limit access turned on / off dynamically
- black/white list certain IP dynamically
- certain request pattern needs to be blocked (this decision needs to be taken dynamically)

for each of these part there are solutions out there (mod_evasive for apache, nginx rate limiter, or even mature at firewall layer

however not everything is dynamic (some services needs restart)

any one has any experience around using such tool that solves these needs efficiently

last resort is to write one

Comment: What type of dynamic access control do you need? Does it have to do with what the user is trying to do with the app? With data inside the app? If so, then check out XACML...

Comment: For example dynamically if I want to block all request with specific user agent, coming with specific referral header

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running a Linux system, have you considered `iptables`?

Basically, you could use something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -dport 80 -m limit --limit 20/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT
```

And use some tweaks to whitelist/blacklist. This way you won't have to restart any service.
See [this resource](https://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/iptables-how-to-use-the-limits-module/) or [this one](https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/20/mitigating-dos-attack-using-iptables/), and [This anwser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163657/set-packet-rate-limit-via-iptables) on unix.stackexchange.com for further informations.

If you're not running linux, I'm sure `pf` can also do that.

Comment: that makes it hard to manage, i was expecting some tool with everything controlled centrally, +1 though for answering